# How to improve the design of a huge table which changes every minute and requires lot of queries?

Tags: database, database-design

```
Schema - person_id, location_id, time_slot, availability
```

So, the table tells me during which periods of the day (divided into time_slots), the person was present at that particular location or not.

So, if time_slots are divided into 10 mins, there are going to be 10*6*24 = 1440 rows for 1 person at 1 location.

1 person may also be present at another 10 locations. So, there are basically, 1440*10 = 14400 rows for every person. Since, I am expect to have 100,000 people in the DB, this problem clearly looks unscalable to me (at least in MySQL).

**The DB should perform well on queries like telling me if person X can be present in location Y from 11 am to 5 pm.**

I cannot think much beyond the obvious solution. I thought of implementing a segment tree type solution, but that seemed very complex. Also, creating another table with larger time slots seemed like a solution.

I think the entire table design has to be changed and am looking for some help with this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your queries are user specific. If thats the case you could enable partitioning on table by User.  This will improve your query performance.

Just found a link with similar use case:
http://www.chrismoos.com/2010/01/31/mysql-partitioning-tables-with-millions-of-rows